# How to update if exists otherwise insert new document?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

How to update if exists otherwise insert new document in javascript/node.js?
I am getting as parameter to function dictionary,if dictionary contains _id  should update, otherwise insert on remote server (I have connection with remote server through mongoose and I have Person schema which I want to insert/update).

Answer (score 72):

In Mongoose, you'd use `Person.update` [per the documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.update). In order to create a document if it doesn't already exist, you need to pass `{ upsert : true }` in the options hash as it defaults to `false`.

i.e.

```
Person.update( { name : 'Ted' }, { name : 'Ted', age : 50 }, { upsert : true }, callback );
```

Comment: update is deprecated.  Use updateOne, updateMany, or bulkWrite instead.

Answer (score 45):

`collection.update` with `upsert:true`. See also [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/).

Comment: Common answers can still have specific examples.

Comment: https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/5.2/interfaces/UpdateOptions.html#upsert

Answer (score 14):

`[db.collection.replaceOne(filter, replacement, options)]` with `upsert:true`

E.g. from [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.replaceOne/):

```
try {    db.restaurant.replaceOne(
            { "name" : "Pizza Rat's Pizzaria" },
            { "_id": 4, "name" : "Pizza Rat's Pizzaria", "Borough" : "Manhattan", "violations" : 8 },
            { upsert: true }    
         ); 
    }
catch (e){ print(e); }
```

Answer (score 11):

For python:

```py
import pymongo

client = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb_address")
db = client.db_name
collection = db[collection_name]

# update 'data' if 'name' exists otherwise insert new document
collection.find_one_and_update({"name": some_name},
                               {"$set": {"data": some_data}},
                               upsert=True)
```