# Mongoose, Nodejs - replace many documents in one I/O?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have an array of objects and I want to store them in a collection using only one I/O operation if it's possible. If any document already exists in the collection I want to replace it, or insert it otherwise.

These are the solutions that I found, but doesn't work exactly as I want:

- `insertMany()`: this doesn't replace the document that already exists, but throws exception instead (This is what I found in the Mongodb documentation, but I don't know if it's the same as mongoose).
- `update()` or ‎`updateMany()` with `upsert = true`: this doesn't help me as well, because here I have to do the same updates to all the to stored documents.
- ‎There is no `replaceMany()` in mongodb or mongoose.

Is there anyone how knows any optimal way to do `replaceMany` using mongoose and node.js

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21344667/6780663

Answer (score 1):

There is `bulkWrite` (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/), which makes it possible to execute multiple operations at once. In your case, you can use it to perform multiple **replaceOne** operations with *upsert*. The code below shows how you can do it with Mongoose:

```
// Assuming *data* is an array of documents that you want to insert (or replace)
const bulkData = data.map(item => (
    {
        replaceOne: {
            upsert: true,
            filter: {
                // Filter specification. You must provide a field that
                // identifies *item*
            },
            replacement: item
        }
    }
));
db.bulkWrite(bulkData);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to query like this:

```
db.getCollection('hotspot').update({
    /Your Condition/
}, {
    $set: {
        "New Key": "Value"
    } 
}, {
    multi: true,
    upsert: true
});
```

It fulfils your requirements..!!!

Comment: With this solution, I have to do the same actions to all the documents that I want to update, but this is not what I want. I want to do get documents from mongodb, update them using a node.js function that I made and then replace the old documents with the new ones.